# Text over image when container have white-space: nowrap;

Tags: html, css

This is a scrollable div that contains some images. The container has `white-space:nowrap` CSS property. I am trying to add a text layer over **each of the images** (Just like bellow image), but I'm unable to do that.

I've tried `position:absolute` on text container  to do that but it breaks `scroll-x`

So how can I do that? Thank you for coming to help me out.

[image]

```css
.sbn::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 0;}
.sbn{overflow-x:scroll;white-space:nowrap;border-radius:5px;}
.sbn img{height:100px;width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="sbn">
<a><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"></a>
<a><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"></a>
<a><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"></a>
<a><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"></a>
<a><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: ***on text container*** which container is this in the code?

Comment: the container has to be added while providing an answer, if I add that here it will break the code and question will be hard to get understand.

Comment: I think you should include it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your text inside a tag

```
<style>
  .sbn::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
  }
  .sbn {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .sbn img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .sbn a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .sbn a span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<div class="sbn">
  <a>
    <span>Test</span>
    <img
      src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"
  /></a>
  <a>
    <span>Test</span
    ><img
      src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"
  /></a>
  <a
    ><span>Test</span
    ><img
      src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"
    /><span>Test</span></a
  >
  <a
    ><span>Test</span
    ><img
      src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"
  /></a>
  <a
    ><span>Test</span
    ><img
      src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/speed-light-spotlights-digital-background_23-2148821702.jpg"
  /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it will not scroll or don't have white-space:nowarp property. You have given example for text over a normal image.

Comment: Sorry didn't checked the code properly. Edited answer with working example please try that

Comment: **Great answer, thank you very much.** It's been late, I solved it with background-image CSS property. But, your solution is better than mine. People who are facing this same issue will find your solution useful.